# IntelliJ IDEA takes too long to show files in the "file/folder selector" dialog

Tags: android, intellij-idea

### *Update (24/01/16)*:

*I'm not sure why, but it doesn't happen anymore, I forgot what I've changed the last time I was using this PC, I remember disabling Google Drive from opening at startup, but not sure that's the reason, the moment I'll figure it out I'll post an update here.*

*Also, since I found no other people having this problem on the Internet, I guess it's a good idea to post solutions in case someone had this problem and solved it for the next user who'll face this problem.*

---

### Problem description:

Whenever I get to the dialog where I open a file or directory (Like "File>Open..." or "import settings") it takes about 50 seconds to show the file tree.
There's nothing shown except "Loading..." and "Nothing to show".

Also, clicking the "X" button or the "Cancel" button does not respond until it finishes with the process of showing the file tree.
The same can be said about dragging a file/folder, it just won't respond until it finishes the slow initialization.

The dialog window itself is responsive all the time, it's not frozen.

Seems like it takes a long time to initialize, and after that it works perfectly (Until the next time I get to this dialog).

#### Technical details:

- I'm using Windows 10 Pro 64bit
- The OS and the software are installed on an SSD
- The directories I'm browsing are on the same SSD
- The project is an Android project

#### Things I've tried:

- Disabling windows indexing
- Running the 64bit version of IntelliJ IDEA
- Running it as administrator
- Invalidating catches and restarting
- Turning off the antivirus (NOD32)

Comment: Not really an answer, but in my case it's because that I'm in a VPN network. Disconnecting from VPN solve it for me (as indicated by all below answers, it most likely involve to a network issue)

Answer (score 12):

Same for me, but I found the culprit in my case.
I have some network drives mapped with drive letters assigned to them, and if those network drives are disconnected but Windows 10 does not notice this and shows them as being connected the "Select path" dialog takes a long time to show the file tree.
So the solution is to set those de facto disconnected network drives to appear "disconnected" in Windows Explorer.
To be more specific, in my case those network drives are mapped in a virtual machine running under VirtualBox; quitting the virtual machine did not make them disconnected for the W10 host.

Comment: Oh thank god. Year later but had the same problem. This worked for me after having reinstalling pycharm and restarting my PC a hundred times. Wish I had read this earlier. The "open file or project" dialogue windows kept only saying "nothing to show". 
Had 2 windows shared network drives that windows could not connect to. I disconnected/removed one and turned on a VPN to be able to connect to the other. Now pycharm works fine. Thought I was going crazy.

Comment: It's 2021, 5.5 years after the original question - and still - the disconnected network drives are causing this problem. I found that selecting all of them in explorer and right-click -> disconnect solves the problem. This happens in Intellij, PyCharm and Webstorm. 
Thanks @mihai-cazac for your answer.

Comment: In my case I had a network drive mapped to a Hyper-V instance. While the virtual machine is offline the network drive shows up as "unavailable" in Windows Explorer. However, in spite of that, IntelliJ still took a long time to open it's file explorer. I had to manually disconnect the drive in Windows Explorer as @lolitop pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not a proper fix, but you can just drag folders onto the IntelliJ desktop icon and it'll open them instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue (caused by a disconnected network drive) and resolved it using a custom property which you can set inside the IDE.

Taken from this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-338/Redesign-file-chooser-dialog

- Go to `Help > Edit Custom Properties...`
- Append `ide.ui.new.file.chooser=true`
- Restart the IDE

This replaces the tree view with a folder view, where the IDE does not need to load all drives and folders beforehand, thus eliminating the long loading time.

Works in PhpStorm and IntelliJ (and I guess in every other JetBrains IDE as well).

Answer (score 0):

- Disable all the plugins that you are not using
- Go to Android Studio folder in the bin folder there is a file named studio64.vmoptions open it and make this change: `-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m` at least (if it is 350m), `-Xms128m` and `-Xmx2048m`

I hope this will help you :/